# How to pass derived object as rvalue reference into base class pointer members using move constructor?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, rvalue-reference, composite, move-constructor

I implemented composite design pattern for calculating the nested mathematical expressions modeled in a binary tree. I need to hold two base class pointers `*left`,`*right` in my derived composite class. Problem arises when I pass the arguments of composite class constructor as rvalues and get segmentation fault, as if `evaluate()` member function is unknown. It works well, when arguments are passed  as lvalues. Here is my whole code.
Appreciate any help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef int (*operation)(int, int);
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
int subtract(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}
    class base_object{
        public:
            virtual int evaluate() = 0;
            virtual ~base_object(){}
    };
    class primitive: public base_object{
        private:
            int value;
        public:
            primitive(int _value): value(_value){}
            primitive(primitive&& primitive):value(std::move(primitive.value)){}
            int evaluate() override{
               return value; 
            }
    };
    
    class composite: public base_object{
        private:
            base_object *left, *right;
            operation op;
        public:
         explicit composite() = delete;
         composite(base_object&& _left, base_object&& _right, operation _op):
                    left(&_left), right(&_right), op(_op){
                    std::cout<<"composite moving constructor was called"<<std::endl;
         }
         composite(base_object *_left, base_object *_right, operation _op):left(_left), right(_right), op(_op){}
         int evaluate() override{
                return op(left->evaluate(), right->evaluate());
         }
    };
int main(){//calculate expression ((10+2)-5)
    composite exp1 = composite(primitive(10), primitive(2), &add);
    composite exp2 = composite(std::move(exp1), primitive(5), &subtract);
    int result = exp2.evaluate();
    std::cout<<"final result of expression="<<result<<std::endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `left` is a pointer to the constructor arguments which are destroyed after the constructor ends, use [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead.

Comment: `left` and `right` must be owning pointers. That is, `std::unique_ptr` (+ `std::make_unique()`) in modern C++. (Or `new` & `delete`, but that's bad practice outside of custom containers/smart pointers, unless you're just trying to learn how `new` works.)

Comment: Also: 1. You don't need `primitive(primitive&& primitive)`, the compiler will generate it for you. 2. Don't write `explicit` default constructors (i.e. ones without parameters), who taught you that? They are mostly useless, and [cause some obscure issues](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aKhrrfEr6).

Comment: Thank you @HolyBlackCat and Ahmed. I tried also shared_ptr approach, but no success. I know the problem originates from the fact that I'm not allowed to instantiate an abstract object.  That's why 'evaluate()' virtual method doesn't resolve in runtime.

Comment: @hamid It has nothing to do with `evaluate()`. As explained above, you (1) pass an R-value reference pointing at a temporary object that only exists while the constructor runs, (2) store a pointer to that temporary object in a field of `composite` and then, **after** the constructor has finished and the temporary object that served as argument has been destroyed, you call `evaluate()`, which accesses an invalid memory location, starting perhaps from some arbitrary place on the stack where the temporary constructor arguments used to be, and that results in _undefined behavior_.

Comment: A possible solution might be: `class composite { /*...*/ std::unique_ptr<base_object> left, right; /*...*/ };` with a constructor like `composite(std::unique_ptr<base_object> _left, std::unique_ptr<base_object> _right, operation _op) : left(std::move(_left)), right(std::move(_right)) {}` and then finally in `main()` you would have `composite exp1{std::make_unique<primitive>(10), std::make_unique<primitive>(2), add};` and the like.

Comment: To pass `exp1` into `exp2`, you have to make it dynamic from the start, such as `std::unique_ptr<composite> exp1{std::make_unique<composite>(std::make_unique<primitive>(10), std::make_unique<primitive>(2), add)}; composite exp2{std::move(exp1), std::make_unique<primitive>(5), subtract};`. Now `exp2` owns `exp1`. To pass `exp2` somewhere further, rinse and repeat, allocate it instead of having it on the stack…

Comment: Thank you @AndrejPodzimek. It worked great. I got a good understanding of relation between rvalues, temporary objects and virtual function resolution.